# EMQ is not connecting to client after enabling emq_web_hook plugin

Tags: mqtt, emq

I am running my emqtt broker by docker image.

I am trying to catch all messages published on my broker and all acknowledged messages. For this purpose I am trying to use emq_web_hook plugin but when I enabled this plugin from dashboard, client disconnects and then unable to connect again to broker. I tried this with default configurations like

```
web.hook.api.url = http://127.0.0.1

web.hook.rule.client.connected.1     = {"action": "on_client_connected"}
web.hook.rule.client.disconnected.1  = {"action": "on_client_disconnected"}
web.hook.rule.client.subscribe.1     = {"action": "on_client_subscribe"}
web.hook.rule.client.unsubscribe.1   = {"action": "on_client_unsubscribe"}
web.hook.rule.session.created.1      = {"action": "on_session_created"}
web.hook.rule.session.subscribed.1   = {"action": "on_session_subscribed"}
web.hook.rule.session.unsubscribed.1 = {"action": "on_session_unsubscribed"}
web.hook.rule.session.terminated.1   = {"action": "on_session_terminated"}
web.hook.rule.message.publish.1      = {"action": "on_message_publish"}
web.hook.rule.message.delivered.1    = {"action": "on_message_delivered"}
web.hook.rule.message.acked.1        = {"action": "on_message_acked"}
```

I also changed the url and provide a url of my node server but it also dis not work.My endpoint was never called.

My dashboard is working but I am unable to publish.

What am I doing wrong or are there any steps I missed?

And How can I catch all those events?

I am confused. Documentation is not clear enough.

Thanks